# Can't read data from BLE devices, onCharacteristicChanged() is never called

Tags: java, android, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been writing a tool to receive bytes from my Arduino devices. I tried the following BluetoothGatt callback class, it can connect to the device shortly  but couldn't receive any data. The onCharacteristicChanged() has never been called.

I used other BLE serial debugging apps on android to ensure that the characteristic UUID "0000fff6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" can receive data. But in my code, it couldn't.

Here's the log from Android Studio:

```
E/BluetoothGatt: STATE_CONNECTED
D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: 3C:A3:08:8B:44:B9
D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=3C:A3:08:8B:44:B9 interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=3C:A3:08:8B:44:B9 Status=0
I/Service UUID: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
I/Service UUID: 0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000fff4-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
I/Service UUID: 0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000fff6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=3C:A3:08:8B:44:B9 interval=36 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=3C:A3:08:8B:44:B9 interval=30 latency=0 timeout=100 status=0
```

After this there's no new log coming in while my Arduino device keeps sending data.

```java
    public int connectDevice(){
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
         bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, new BluetoothGattCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
                Log.e("BluetoothGatt", "Connecting state:" + newState);
                if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    Log.e("BluetoothGatt", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                    bluetoothGatt = gatt;
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                }
                else if(newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTING){
                    Log.e("BluetoothGatt", "Connecting");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
                List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
                for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
                    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
                    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic character : characteristics) {
                        enableNotification(gatt, service.getUuid(), character.getUuid());
                    }
                }
            }

             @Override
             public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                 super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
                 byte[] value = characteristic.getValue();
                 Log.i("BLE", "receive value ----------------------------");
                 for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                     Log.w("BLE", "character_value = " + value[i]);
                 }
             }
        });

        return 0;
    }

    public boolean enableNotification(BluetoothGatt gatt, UUID serviceUUID, UUID characteristicUUID) {
        boolean success = false;
        BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(serviceUUID);
        if (service != null) {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = findNotifyCharacteristic(service, characteristicUUID);
            if (characteristic != null) {
                Log.i("Service UUID", serviceUUID.toString());
                success = gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
                if (success) {

                    for (BluetoothGattDescriptor dp : characteristic.getDescriptors()) {
                        if (dp != null) {
                            if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) != 0) {
                                dp.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                            } else if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) != 0) {
                                dp.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
                            }
// I just commented this line but still not working                 
// dp.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE); 
                            gatt.writeDescriptor(dp);
                            gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic findNotifyCharacteristic(BluetoothGattService service, UUID characteristicUUID) {
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = null;
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic c : characteristics) {
            if ((c.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) != 0
                    && characteristicUUID.equals(c.getUuid())) {
                characteristic = c;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (characteristic != null)
            return characteristic;
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic c : characteristics) {
            if ((c.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) != 0
                    && characteristicUUID.equals(c.getUuid())) {
                characteristic = c;
                break;
            }
        }
        return characteristic;
    }
```

No matter what I do the `onCharacteristicChanged()` will never be called. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Does your remote device supports Indications or Notifications? Now you enable Indications and not Notifications. Also your code doesn't wait for a previous GATT operation to complete before you execute the next one. Please fix that also.

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed these two problems but still can't receive data. I added a sleep of 500 ms in my enableNotification function, is that right?

Comment: No that sleep won't change anything because callbacks happen in sequence. After you have called writeDescriptor you must wait for the onDescriptorWrite callback until you can call readCharacteristic or writeDescriptor for the next characteristic again.